# Change “add to cart” button text for products that have "no price" and "out of stock"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the "add to cart" text button for products that meet the following conditions:

- empty price
- out of stock

The intention is to change the text to "Not available right now"

---

Here is an example image to clarify my question

[image]

---

This is the code that I use. But I can't make it work. Any ideas of where I am going wrong?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'price_zero_empty', 9999, 2 );
function price_zero_empty( $price, $product ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $stock == 'outofstock' && '' == $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price()  ) {
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_readmore_text', 20, 3 );         
}
function change_readmore_text(){
            if (! is_admin() && $domain === 'woocommerce'  && $price === 0 && $translated_text === 'Read more') {
                $translated_text = 'Not available right now';}
                return $translated_text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the text for products that have "no price" and are "out of stock", you can use the `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` filter hook.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    // Price empty & Product is out of stock
    if ( empty ( $product->get_price() ) && $product->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock' ) {
        $add_to_cart_text = __( 'Not available right now', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $add_to_cart_text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```